# VB.net 2013 select from combobox and fill datagridview

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I am new to vb.net and have tried searching with no success, so here is what i am trying to do.

I have created a windows form with a combobox that has a datasource of a column in a sql database. When a option is picked i want it to run a query in the database to pull out only the info selected and display in datagridview.

the code i am using to fill the combobox is  `Me.SCAN_DATATableAdapter.Fill(Me.QADataSet.SCAN_DATA)`

The code i was trying to use for datagridview is

```
 DataGridView1.DataSource = SCAN_DATATableAdapter.GetData("SELECT PROD_ORDER_NUM, CUST_SEQ_NUM FROM SCAN_DATA WHERE (PROD_ORDER_NUM = " & ComboBox1.SelectedText & ")")
```

Comment: Your code doesnt match the question.  Rather than `a datasource of a column`, the code treats the CBO text like it is a row identifier.  Also, `SelectedText ` is probably not what you think it is.

Comment: I changed the `SelectedText` to just `Text` which seemed to correct the issue of getting the correct info from the combobox, but i still cannot get it to do a query in the table to return the results based on the combobox selection.